# google visualization api version

Tags: java, gwt

I can't find a solution for my problem, probably because it's too new. I use the method
`VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(java.lang.Runnable onLoad, java.lang.String... packages)` 
from the google visualization api in two different web applications. It works fine in one but not in the other application. I spent hours to find out why, but could not find out what exactly makes the difference between the two applications.

The problem is that the callback method in the Runnable parameter is never called when `CoreChart.PACKAGE` is used as one of the 'packages' parameter. In the Firebug console an error "ReferenceError: iT is not defined" ("oT" on a different machine) is displayed. I'm not sure whether the error message is related.

Since this never happened before yesterday, when the new version was released, it seems to be a bug in the new version. What would be the best way to submit a bug report? The applications are too big to post the source code without knowing where to look. I could not reproduce the problem in an example application. Where can I look for the problem?

Something that would help me already would be the possibility to use the former version of the api. I know I can pass the version as a String to the loadVisualizationApi. What do I need to pass if I want to use the version from before Nov. 26 2013?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you wrap this tooltip in GWT can you share it here. @user3044395 i also needed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested the reason was that the method was called 4 times in total, with different package parameters each time. Removing the unnecessary calls fixed it.